# What is a good way to visualize the movement of an Alcubierre drive?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, faster-than-light, warp-drives

So I know that an AD works by pinching space-time in front of the ship and expanding it behind the ship.
A good way to describe gravity is having a blanket stretched out on all four corners and dropping a bowling ball in the middle. That mass curves the flat blanket down and if you put a tennis ball down, it will follow the curvature towards the bowling ball.
https://media1.shmoop.com/images/physics/forces/physicsbook_forces_graphik_38.png

so with the AD, would it be appropriate to say that a ship moves when the blanet is titled downward. Like a ball rolling down a hill?

Comment: Two-dimensional blankets don’t provide much real insight into four-dimensional spacetime.